# d3 - create lines based on max count of data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Here's a series of lines that is being created using `d3` for loop where the number of instances is manually defined. Suppose I have a external data with some `n` number of rows. And i want to create lines for those many rows.

**Lines created using for loop :**

```
var height = 200;
var width = 1000;
var count = 50, padding = 11;
var svgContianer = d3.select(".spectrum")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("class", "g")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)

for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var line = svgContianer.append("line")
                            .attr("x1", padding*i)
                            .attr("x2", padding*i)
                            .attr("y1", 90)
                            .attr("y2", 25)
                            .attr("stroke", "#555")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 10)

}
```

But when i use it like this. It's not working.

```
var height = 200;
var width = 1000;
var count = 50, padding = 11;
var svgContianer = d3.select(".spectrum")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("class", "g")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)


d3.csv("data2.csv", function(data, error) {

    var line = svgContianer.selectAll("line")
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                            .append("line")
                            .attr("x1", padding*i)
                            .attr("x2", padding*i)
                            .attr("y1", 90)
                            .attr("y2", 25)
                            .attr("stroke", "#555")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 10)
                            .on("mouseover", movein)
                            .on("mouseout", moveout)

})
```

Some one help in creating lines for the number of rows in the external data.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwCnM/)

**DATA :**

```
time,count
00:12,1
00:45,1
01:14,1
01:30,1
01:57,1
02:21,1
02:44,1
02:50,1
03:13,1
03:41,1
03:59,1
04:10,1
04:23,1
04:45,1
04:59,1
05:01,1
05:17,1
05:48,1
06:00,1
06:11,1
06:23,1
06:31,1
06:47,1
07:12,1
07:29,1
07:41,1
07:58,1
```

Comment: Can you verify if the file is getting loaded? Try to output the data using console.log(data), so verify if the data is coming through. Another thing is change padding*i to function(d,i){ return padding * i;}

Comment: I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: This means you are not able to read the file. Therefore,data is null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that `i` is not defined in you piece of code. 
What you can do is:

```
.attr("x1", function(d,i){return padding*i})
```

with:

- `d` being the data attached to a single line (the element of the `data` array corresponding to the line)
- `i` being the index of the element in the `data` array.

Comment: How do it add x-axis to this lines using the `time` in the data. I would like that to 30 mins interval.

Comment: Look at d3 tutorials. There are tons of examples of this on stackoverflow.com itself.